# Amazon EC2 does allow access to website

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My company's website is running on Amazon AWS instance. Everything was fine till date but recently our website is not accessible from our organization's internet (We have static IP). Website is accessible from devices having different IPs. I tried using traceroute, from my organization's internet:

```
3   297 ms   296 ms   301 ms  nyiix-peering.amazon.com [198.32.160.64]
4   324 ms   330 ms   323 ms  178.236.3.177
5   314 ms   262 ms   309 ms  72.21.222.212
6   308 ms   308 ms   311 ms  205.251.244.6
7   312 ms   311 ms     *     72.21.220.53
8   285 ms   284 ms   285 ms  205.251.245.65
9     *        *        *     Request timed out.
10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
12   284 ms   287 ms   284 ms  216.182.224.241
13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Can anybody help for what might be going wrong? We are able to SSH onto our server from the organization's internet though.

Comment: If you can SSH, there's not much to see with traceroute, since you know you have connectivity...

Comment: Then can you suggest how to debug?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site using the IP in the browser, instead of hostname?  Have you tried pinging the site by hostname (not by ip?) Or "nslookup websitedomainname" from an office computer?

Comment: 1) Tried accessing website through IP, not working.
2) Tried pinging website through hostname as well as IP address. Both failed. 
3) nslookup websitedomainname gives me the correct ip address.

Comment: `telnet websitehostname 80` should either respond with one of three possibilities: connected, or timed out, or connection refused.  Which response you get would be useful info to know. (We're using telnet to get a tcp connection to the web server and possibly a more helpful error than provided by the browser, we're not trying to "telnet to" the server).

Comment: I got timed out response.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Now I am getting Connection to host lost. Any idea? Website is accessible from everywhere except my internet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your static IP blocked by your instance. check if you have configured hosts.deny. It might have added your static IP o blocked list

Comment: Checked, nope, my IP is not present there.